# VB Error when convert in .EXE file

Tags: database, vb6, runtime-error, exe

My system wont open when i did convert it to .exe file. Although when im in VB Workspace, then run it. It works fine. I wonder where can i find my error or something like that. I don't get it.
I put screenshots below:
[image: When i click the file this is the output]
[image: then this one]

I dont know if this issue has been solved here. Yet i can't find any answers. :( Please help. Thankyou 

*PS: Should i put my codes?*

I put it anyway. 

This picture is the property of my Adodc1 object
Connecting to my Database. (Some of my database was like this, then works fine. Its just that i got warned on the tblu.

[image: Property of Adodc1 where i connect my Database]

this is the only code in the Form_Load()
[image: Form_Load() Code]

PLEASE HELP :'(

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: Based on your error, your exe file is looking in the wrong place for your table, and your design time instance is looking in the right one.